# PHP array_search not working searching for string zero

Tags: php, arrays, search

Finds '1' and '2' - but not zero '0'

```
$My_Array = array('0', '1', '2');

        if(array_search('0', $My_Array)){
            echo "FOUND";
        }else{
            echo "NOT FOUND";
        }
```

In this case - 0 being a string - why does it not find the zero?

Comment: 0 gets casted to false

Comment: but it is a string?

Comment: yes, but it is PHP

Comment: lol... I still don't get it 0_o

Comment: PHP is weird, not much else to say

Comment: OK... Maybe I should delete this question? so I don't look SO stupid :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of php.net [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues) function,

> **Returns the key** for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Now comes to your question:

> why does it not find the zero?

Yes, it does find. Look at the following line,

```
if(array_search('0', $My_Array)){ ...
```

In this case `array_search()` function will return `0` which is the index of element `'0'` in the array. And because of this, the `if` block will get executed like this:

```
if(0){ ...
```

which basically evaluates to `false`, and this means the control goes to `else` block even if it finds element `'0'` in the array.

So **the solution** is, change your `if` block in the following way:

```
if(array_search('0', $My_Array) !== false){
```

Comment: Ugh!... I'm so stupid... I should have seen that :/ ... I actually was using it just like that about 10 lines down from where I had this code.... 0_o

Comment: it is returning the key [0]

Comment: I was just losing my mind until I found this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
>   first corresponding key if successful

The key here is 0. if(0) results in false, hence it displays not found. PHP is doing exactly what it claims to do